# Customizing Buy now button on WooCommerce

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have already made the Buy it now button using the direct checkout plugin but I would like to make it a bit taller, the width to be exactly until the quantity box and make the text bigger and bold. I think this can be done using additional CSS but I am not sure how to do it myself.

I only care about how this looks looks on mobile.

[Buttons Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNjb5.jpg)

[Store](http://isetupedia.com)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn css, even if it is basics.  Because we cannot know how you want the button to look like.

Secondly, in a browser, you can just right-click on the button and select from the pop-up menu "Inspect".  It will open the Developer Tools screen.  When you look at the 'Styles' tab, it will give you the current element values and in which CSS Stylesheet you can find these.  Thus, you will need to use your own Child Theme style.css to plot your new design elements.

Or

There is most possibly a plugin for the WooCommerce button styles.  I cannot recommend you any because I, myself work manually.  But I hope that I can get you a step ahead in finding out what you could research next.